# How to convert a Chrome extension widget into a website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was reading this article on how to convert website into a google chrome extension [1] and I was wondering how could we achieve the oposite? Like imagine a chrome extension that is a widget where you can fill a form. How can we embed the extension into a website?

We use a private chrome extension that is just a "form" to create Jiras. So now we want to make that form into it's own website but wonder if there's a way to "embed" the current widget into a website so we don't have to maintain two repositories.

Any reference you can share?

[1] http://mytypings.com/converting-website-to-a-google-chrome-extension/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your extension like website by going to `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/<your popup page>.html`

or use the [Plasmo](https://docs.plasmo.com/) Framework to create [Tab Pages](https://docs.plasmo.com/browser-extension/tab-pages) you want.

Comment: thanks for these! at a first look, it looks promising. On the first option, what should I use under "<your popup page>.html"? when opening extension to fill it out, it's a floating widget and doesn't have a URL I can use. It's more like a dialog and when inspecting it's a under div tag. Can you give me an example how to use the first option? thanks!

Comment: right click your extension to inspect -> now you're in DevTools -> go to Sources tab -> you will see file name that got highlighted on the left side that is `<your popup page>`, e.g. popup.html

Comment: hm, doesn't seem to grab the "widget" html, still best answer Will investigate the second option